# autohotkey switch mouse buttons not working on WIndows 10, why?

Tags: windows-10, autohotkey

I am trying to write simple ahk script to swap the mouse buttons (left btn becomes right btn and vice-versa). Yet, I don't want to reboot the system. I have tried these two scripts I found online but they did not work on Windows 10 for me.

trial 1:

```
MsgBox When ok is pressed, the mouse buttons will be swapped.
DllCall("SwapMouseButton","uInt",true)
```

trial 2:

```
MsgBox When ok is pressed, the mouse buttons will be swapped.
Lbutton::Rbutton
Rbutton::Lbutton
```

Anyone cares to share a script that reverses the mouse button that works on Windows 10?

Comment: Try to run the script as administrator (works for me on Windows 10).

Comment: Just tested in Windows 10 on v1.1.25.01 (latest), and the script under "trial 2" worked just fine. Perhaps the version being used is out of date, or the script was not being reloaded to take on the new changes?